# Slather failing - running Sonar-Qube with an Xcode project. Error code: 127

Tags: swift, xcode, sonarqube, slather

I am running a Sonar script and and it has a "Slather Coverage" command in it, and it is erroring out with the following error message:

*ERROR - Command* '*slather coverage --binary-basename GC --input-format profdata -i .*Tests.* --cobertura-xml --output-directory sonar-reports --scheme GC GC.xcodeproj' failed with error code: 127*

Anybody know what error code 127 is?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
sudo gem install slather
```